# unable to read properly list file from Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

My flutter project runs properly on an android simulator. But when i run it on an iOS simulator I get the following error.

I tried build clean but still not working.
If you need more information please let me know.

Any help will be really appreciated :)[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem i managed to fix it. You have to change the boolean tag for io.flutter.embedded_views_preview boolean tag to true/. Get rid of the boolean statement.